# SAPUI5: Populate ODataModel async to prepare data for the view

Tags: odata, sapui5, sap-fiori

My mobile cordova application uses OData service that returns a list of let's say Products. Each call to backend takes 5-10 seconds.
On the start view I have several tiles including: "My Products". When user clicks on the tile "My Products" he is routed to view "My Product List" with a List control. So this navigation step takes about 5-10 seconds and UI hangs.

Now I want to start populating ODataModel for user's products List in the background to save some time and prepare data before user clicks on tile "My Products". As I see populating the model is possible via binding but it works only sync. Any async model methods like "read" do not store the data in it. So is it possible to populate oDataModel in the background?

Ideally is to show product count in the number attribute of "My Products" tile soon after the model is populated.

Thanks!
Anton

Answer (score 0):

The OData requests are by default asynchronous in the SAPUI5 Framework.

You can check this here: https://sapui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/sdk/#docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.model.odata.ODataModel.html#read

The parameter bAsync is True by default.

So you could set your tile to be busy until the background read of the OData service has finished.

Comment: read() is just an async request that does not store data in the model. But I need to store data in the model to be used by further views (List) to avoid further time consuming requests. Ideally to bund a StandardTile to $count property and then reuse the data in List control. But looks like StandardTile does not support "{/Products/$count}" syntax